# Using ArrayList for user input

Tags: java, arraylist, input, java.util.scanner, user-input

I want to allow the user to input strings until a blank line is entered, and have the strings stored in an ArrayList. I have the following code and I think it's right, but obviously not.

```
String str = " "; 
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();     
System.out.println("Please enter words");
while (sc.hasNextLine() && !(str = sc.nextLine()).equals("")) {
    list.add(sc.nextLine());
} 

for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Every time you call `sc.nextLine()` it reads ***another*** line from the user. What do you think happens when you call it once in the `while` loop condition, and once in the body of the loop? Why are you setting `str` to the value it returned but never using `str` again?

Answer (score 2):

You consume the next line one time more as you can as you invoke a single time `sc.hasNextLine()` but twice `sc.nextLine()`.
Instead, invoke a single time `nextLine()` and then use the variable where you stored the result to retrieve the read line  :

```
while (sc.hasNextLine() && !(str = sc.nextLine()).equals("")) {
    list.add(str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Why is it list.add(str) and not list.add(sc)? I declared str = " " so wouldn't it be just adding " " to the arraylist?

Comment: You are welcome :) You don't want and you cannot add a `Scanner` object to a `List` of `String` but you want to add `String`s in. The second boolean expresion of your `while` statement prevents to add an empty String in the List :  `and !(str = sc.nextLine()).equals("")`